# Unable to change @Path in NetBeans and GlassFish

Tags: jax-rs, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I created a simple entity and then used NetBeans "create rest services from entity" wizard to generate the rest resource. All good so far. It gives a `@Path` of the entity package to the resource as follows:

```
@Stateless
@Path("org.hellorest.entity.project")
public class ProjectFacadeREST extends AbstractFacade<Project> {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "HelloRestPersistanceUnit")
    private EntityManager em;
...
...
}
```

I am able to hit the end point at `localhost:8081/HelloRest/resources/org.hellorest.entity.project/133`

I changed the `@Path` to `@Path("project")`. I am not able to hit the end points at this path. The old longer path still works. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the old class is still loaded by the server.

If this happens you should `Clean & Build` your NetBeans project. This should undeploy the application. `Run` the project to redeploy the application.

If it still doesn't work a restart of the server before redeploying may help.

There is an option in the NetBeans project properties in the `Run` tab named `Deploy on Save`. If this is enabled (it is by default), changed classes should be recompiled and redeployed automatically, but sometimes this doesn't work because GlassFish hasn't properly unloaded the class.

**See also:**

- [Netbeans deploy on save: how is it supposed to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18451517/netbeans-deploy-on-save-how-is-it-supposed-to-work)